# tensorflow serving model load affects other model graph run tail latency

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-serving, recommendation-engine

I'm loading two models A and B using the same tensorflow model server instance (running inside a single Docker container).
(using tensorflow_model_sever v2.5.1)

the models are ~5GB on disk, of which about 1.7GB is just the inference related nodes.

model A is only loaded once, and model B gets a new version every once in a while.
my client only requests predictions from model A. model B isn't used.
incidentally, both models have warmup data.

every time a new version is loaded for model B, the tail latency for graph runs in model A jumps from 20msec to > 100msec (!).
I'm getting the tail latency both from tensorflow model server - :tensorflow:serving:request_latency_bucket,
as well as from my GRPC client.

the container has plenty of available memory and CPU,
this is also seen with a GPU.

I tried changing num_load_threads and num_unload_threads, flush_filesystem_caches,
but to no avail.

so far didn't manage to get rid of it using GRPC hedging/manual double dispatch (but working on it), anybody ever seen this, and better yet managed to get over this?
thanks!